# mostra 3 campos personalizados com condições

Tags: php, wordpress

tenho esse codigo aqui:

```
<?php if ( custom_get_meta( 'Plot') == true ) { ?> // campo principal
<?php echo custom_get_meta( 'Plot' ); ?> // campo principal a mostrar
<?php } else { ?>
<?php the_content(); ?> // se não existir o campo principal, mostrar "the_content"
<?php } ?>
```

mas só dá para 2 campos personalizados, agora eu queria adicionar outro campo como principal...

vai ser
custom_get_meta( 'sinopse' );
senão tiver "sinopse" vai buscar "Plot",
se não tiver "sinopse" nem "Plot" vai buscar "the_content();"

Answer (score 0):

Segue o código correto:

```
<?php
if ( custom_get_meta( 'sinopse') ) {
    echo custom_get_meta( 'sinopse' );
} else if ( custom_get_meta( 'Plot') ) {
    echo custom_get_meta( 'Plot' );
} else {
     the_content();
} 
?>
```

Comment: muito obrigado, funciona!

Comment: @jitas vota na minha resposta então por favor, quero aumentar reputação, comecei agora.